# Generating random number in a given range in Fortran 77

Tags: random, fortran, text-files, fortran77

I am a beginner trying to do some engineering experiments using fortran 77. I am using Force 2.0 compiler and editor. I have the following queries:

1. How can I generate a random number between a specified range, e.g. if I need to generate a single random number between 3.0 and 10.0, how can I do that?
2. How can I use the data from a text file to be called in calculations in my program. e.g I have temperature, pressure and humidity values (hourly values for a day, so total 24 values in each text file).
3. Do I also need to define in the program how many values are there in the text file?

Comment: @Evansbee - it doesn't really matter with fortran. As long as it follows the standard, it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

Knuth has [released into the public domain sources in both C and FORTRAN](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/news02.html#rng) for the pseudo-random number generator described in section 3.6 of *The Art of Computer Programming*.

Answer (score 1):

2nd question:

If your file, for example, looks like:

```
hour temperature pressure humidity
00   15          101325   60
01   15          101325   60
... 24 of them, for each hour one
```

this simple program will read it:

```
implicit none
integer hour, temp, hum
real p
character(80) junkline
open(unit=1, file='name_of_file.dat', status='old')
rewind(1)
read(1,*)junkline
do 10 i=1,24
read(1,*)hour,temp,p,hum
 C   do something here ...
 10  end
close(1)
end
```

(the indent is a little screwed up, but I don't know how to set it right in this weird environment)

My advice: read up on data types (INTEGER, REAL, CHARACTER), arrays (DIMENSION), input/output (READ, WRITE, OPEN, CLOSE, REWIND), and loops (DO, FOR), and you'll be doing useful stuff in no time.

I never did anything with random numbers, so I cannot help you there, but I think there are some intrinsic functions in fortran for that. I'll check it out, and report tomorrow. As for the 3rd question, I'm not sure what you ment (you don't know how many lines of data you'll be having in a file ? or ?)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check your compiler manual for the specific random number generator function, but chances are it generates random numbers between 0 and 1.  This is easy to handle - you just scale the interval to be the proper width, then shift it to match the proper starting point: i.e. to map `r` in `[0, 1]` to `s` in `[a, b]`, use `s = r*(b-a) + a`, where `r` is the value you got from your random number generator and `s` is a random value in the range you want.

[Idigas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896187/generating-random-number-in-a-given-range-in-fortran-77/896244#896244) covers your second question well - read in data using formatted input, then use them as you would any other variable.

For your third question, you will need to define how many lines there are in the text file only if you want to do something with all of them - if you're looking at reading the line, processing it, then moving on, you can get by without knowing the number of lines ahead of time.  However, if you are looking to store all the values in the file (e.g. having arrays of temperature, humidity, and pressure so you can compute vapor pressure statistics), you'll need to set up storage somehow.  Typically in FORTRAN 77, this is done by pre-allocating an array of a size larger than you think you'll need, but this can quickly become problematic.  Is there any chance of switching to Fortran 90?  The updated version has much better facilities for dealing with standardized dynamic memory allocation, not to mention many other advantages.  I would *strongly* recommend using F90 if at all possible - you will make your life much easier.

Another option, depending on the type of processing you're doing, would be to investigate algorithms that use only single passes through data, so you won't need to store everything to compute things like means and standard deviations, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This subroutine generate a random number in fortran 77 between 0 and ifin
where i is the seed; some great number such as 746397923

```
    subroutine rnd001(xi,i,ifin)
    integer*4 i,ifin
    real*8 xi
    i=i*54891
    xi=i*2.328306e-10+0.5D00
    xi=xi*ifin
    return
    end
```

You may modifies in order to take a certain range.

Comment: What is the quality of this generator? Which established tests does it or does it not pass succesfully?

Comment: That is not very assuring. What does "pretty pseudorandom" mean? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests

Comment: Yes,  I remember to have been used ENT to test the sieries that was almost 15 years ago or something similar.